# Linux unzip list with mask fails to extract all matching files

Tags: linux, archive, unzip

I have a zip archive on Linux into which I load every day ~20 files with date (formatted yyyymmdd) in the name.
I need to extract all files from selected day, so I check if they are in the archive

```
unzip -l fileArchive.zip | grep 20160910
```

and in result I see 17 files which is what I expected:

```
 32471137  09-12-2016 21:07   TRANSACTIONS_20160910.csv
      181  09-13-2016 21:00   FILE1_D_20160910.CSV
     9345  09-13-2016 21:00   FILE2_D_20160910.CSV
      142  09-13-2016 21:00   FILE3_D_20160910.CSV
  6307637  09-13-2016 21:00   FILE4_D_20160910.CSV
   783975  09-13-2016 21:01   FILE5_D_20160910.CSV
     4812  09-13-2016 21:01   FILE6_D_20160910.CSV
    88306  09-13-2016 21:01   FILE7_D_20160910.CSV
       47  09-13-2016 21:01   G_TEXTE000_D_20160910.CSV
      510  09-13-2016 21:01   FILE9_D_20160910.CSV
   163646  09-13-2016 21:01   FILE10_D_20160910.CSV
       51  09-13-2016 21:02   FILE11_D_20160910.CSV
   158654  09-13-2016 21:02   FILE12_D_20160910.CSV
    31724  09-13-2016 21:02   FILE13_D_20160910.CSV
   269337  09-13-2016 21:02   FILE14_D_20160910.CSV
       89  09-13-2016 21:02   FILE15_D_20160910.CSV
       76  09-13-2016 21:03   FILE16_D_20160910.CSV
       70  09-13-2016 21:01   FILE17_D_20160910.CSV
```

In the next step I want to extract those files using unzip with mask in place of list of files to extract:

```
unzip  fileArchive.zip *20160910* -d /var/tmp/
```

and the result is only one file extracted:

```
Archive:  fileArchive.zip
  inflating: /var/tmp/G_TEXTE000_D_20160910.CSV
```

which is surely wrong, because when I do identical operation with other mask, unzip command with mask extracts all files that are previously listed by unzip -l.
Happily I can unzip all those files by giving exact names in list:

```
unzip  fileArchive.zip TRANSACTIONS_20160910.csv FILE1_D_20160910.CSV FILE2_D_20160910.CSV ... FILE17_D_20160910.CSV -d /var/tmp/
```

So the archive is not corrupted. Simply unzip for this one day 20160910 fails on using mask.

Do You have any idea what may be wrong?
Regards,

**Edited**:
Below is the full code (pieces of file names are cut) that shows that mask without quotation marks works for symmetric archive "sk", and for this one "cz" it does not.

I unzip "cz" files with quotation marks - works fine
change dir and unzip "sk" files without quotation marks - works fine
change dir and try to unzip "cz" files without quotation marks - only one file is unzipped.

```
$ pwd
/root_path/cz/input_data/fileArchive
$ unzip  fileArchive.zip '*20160910*' -d /var/tmp/
Archive:  fileArchive.zip
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_C_BAL_D_20160910.csv
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_ERNAL_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_A2iMX_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_MENT_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_IER0_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_VIDU_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_ONNEL_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_ENT0_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_E000_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_IST0_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_STE_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_TLOG_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_ENTS_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_ERE0_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_VIDU_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_TEG_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_TEGY_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ__ECH_D_20160910.CSV
$ pwd
/root_path/cz/input_data/fileArchive
$ cd /root_path/sk/input_data/fileArchive
$ unzip  fileArchive.zip *20160910* -d /var/tmp/
Archive:  fileArchive.zip
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_D_20160910.csv
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_XTERNAL_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_X_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_MENT_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_IER0_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_VIDU_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_ONNEL_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_ENT0_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_E000_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_IST0_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_STE_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_TLOG_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_ENTS_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_ERE0_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_VIDU_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_TEG_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK_TEGY_D_20160910.CSV
  inflating: /var/tmp/SK__ECH_D_20160910.CSV
$ cd /root_path/cz/input_data/fileArchive
$ unzip  fileArchive.zip *20160910* -d /var/tmp/
Archive:  fileArchive.zip
replace /var/tmp/CZ_E000_D_20160910.CSV? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
  inflating: /var/tmp/CZ_E000_D_20160910.CSV
```

This is awkward!
I would expect mask quotation to work on both archives the same way

Comment: What is the output of `ls -hl /root_path/sk/input_data/fileArchive`?

Comment: I did for both dirs: `ls -hl /root_path/sk/input_data/fileArchive` 
returns `-rwxrwx---+ 1 jd74630 root 1.2G Nov  3 21:36 fileArchive.zip`
for cz returns
`-rwxrwx---+ 1 jd74630 root 4.1G Nov  3 21:36 fileArchive.zip`
Interesting is that now unzip with mask works _only_ with quotation marks

Comment: At some point, you accidentally unzipped the files into `/root_path/sk/input_data/fileArchive`. Later, you removed them.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood You. Of course those files were earlier (many trials) extracted to the target directory. My issue is not prompt if I want to replace or rename. My issue is that after processing this one (CZ_E000_D_20160910.CSV) file none of the remaining matching mask was extracted. But with quotation mark on the mask, remaining files were extracted.
I cleared the target folder and repeated the experiment. Result is that

Answer (score 2):

The man page for `unzip(1)` says

> Be sure to quote any character that might otherwise be interpreted or modified by the operating system, particularly under Unix and VMS.

Try

```
unzip fileArchive.zip '*20160910*' -d /var/tmp/
```

Comment: Thanks! **This helped.** Only strange thing is that I have another symmetric archive for another country files. And with this second archive there was no this issue. All listed files for 20160910 were then unzipped.

Comment: Had you previously unzipped the files? Without the single quotes, the shell will expand the `*20160910*` into a list of files.

Comment: No those files, but files with the same names from symmetric archive in different location. I will paste output in the main field - here is too long.

Comment: I am going to guess that you already extracted the files to `/root_path/cz/input_data/fileArchive`, so the wildcard passed that file list to `unzip`.

Comment: No, those files are not extracted to this location. Temporary they are being dropped to other directory, then automated process imports them to database and OS command `zip IMPORTED_FILE -m fileArchive/fileArchive.zip`